# A value in select box can't be select if once clicked

Tags: php, javascript, select

i hava made a select box of skills..there are skills listed in it.. if we select it once it will be added out side in a DIV..n the first thing what i want is it can't be select again in the select box if once it's there in DIV...n there's a 'x' there in div..if it's clicked..that div will b deleted...
now my point is. the second thing what i wnt is when the value of DIV is deleted by clicking on 'X'...the same value of it in the select box will b live again(we can select it(enabled))...

This is the javascript i used in this tuts..

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var i=0;
  function generateTextbox(){
   if(i<5){
var d=document.getElementById("div");
    var skilldiv=document.getElementById("skill").value;
    d.innerHTML+="<div>"+skilldiv+"<a  class='close_notification' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); '>X</a></div>";
 i=i+1;
}
 }

  </script>
```

select box values come dynamically..

```
<select id="skill" name="skill" multiple="multiple" style="float:left; height:160px; width:375px;" onchange="generateTextbox();">
<?php    foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
$fivesdraft->skill_name;
$fivesdraft->skill_id;



?>
 <option value="<?php echo $fivesdraft->skill_name; ?>" onclick="this.disabled='disabled';"  > <?php echo    $fivesdraft->skill_name; ?></option>

       <?php } ?>                 
                  </select>
 }

</script>


<?php } ?>
```

And this is the div where my select box values come after click on them...

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this: http://aloksah.org/listbox/listbox.html

**jQuery Code:**

```
// function: UnAssignment
function assignList()
{
    // loop through first listbox and append to second listbox
    $('#firstList :selected').each(function(i, selected){
        // append to second list box
        $('#secondList').append('<option value="'+selected.value+'">'+ selected.text+'</option>');
        // remove from first list box
        $("#firstList option[value='"+ selected.value +"']").remove();
    });
}
// function: UnAssignment
function unassignList()
{
    // loop through second listbox and append to first listbox
    $('#secondList :selected').each(function(i, selected){
        // append to first list box
        $('#firstList').append('<option value="'+selected.value+'">'+ selected.text+'</option>');
        // remove from second list box
        $("#secondList option[value='"+ selected.value +"']").remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy..its very helpful for me...i checked your link...there's whole tutorial on this... n i'm new here..n dont knw how to accept ur answer to build your reputation...or is it automatically added on my comment?? @Praveen Kumar

Comment: @user1436528 There will be Accept Answer button below my question's vote count. Just wait for another day and check it. :)

Comment: ok i'll...In this tutorial...when we click on the first list box..it goes to the second list box and vice versa...can we do something ..like when we click on the fist list box ..the value goes to the second list box and also it is there in first list box(i'd be disabled if it's there in the second list box) and when we clicked that value in the second list box..it'll be come alive in the first list box and removed from second list box...
I hope You understand what i actually want...thanks..! :)

Comment: i add an attribute(attr('disabled','disabled') in assignList function just in place of remove() to just disable that perticular value..but still when i click on that disabled value in the first List boxd it goes there in the second listbox. Do you have any idea to get ride of this problem... :/ @Pravin Kumar thanx in adv.. :)

Comment: You can just change it to `<optgroup>` from `<option>`.

Comment: i did but value could not be loaded when i change it to optgroup...
Rather i've changed ..          $('#firstList').click(function() {
 assignList();
 with
    $('#firstList').change(function() {
 assignList();
and it works fine... :) and i also change some code in second list box...when it's clicked the first list value will be alive.. :)
so now its done.. 
Thanks Pravin for your help... :)